# Difference between #include <limits.h> and #inlcude <linux/limits.h>

Tags: c, header, include, limit

In my code i am using the variable PATH_MAX for a buffer size. I had a problem when i was including the library who is supposed to define it `#include <limits.h>`. When i use this library my IDE doesn't recognize the variable as being define but when I include the library like `#include <linux/limits.h>` there is no problem and the variable is define. My question is what is the difference between both of them and will it cause problem when I will cross-compile my project ?

Thank you for all answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limits.h header is a standard header that all implementations are required to supply.  This contains numerical limits such as `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` among others.  `PATH_MAX` is *not* part of this file.

The linux/limits.h header is specific to Linux.  It is here that `PATH_MAX` is defined.

Comment: It depends which linux/limits.h you mean. The one installed as /usr/include/linux/limits.h is Linux-specific but is intended for userspace applications or userspace libraries (glibc for example).

Comment: Yes, good catch.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

linux/limits.h is a very small header file:

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
#ifndef _LINUX_LIMITS_H
#define _LINUX_LIMITS_H

#define NR_OPEN         1024

#define NGROUPS_MAX    65536    /* supplemental group IDs are available */
#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
#define LINK_MAX         127    /* # links a file may have */
#define MAX_CANON        255    /* size of the canonical input queue */
#define MAX_INPUT        255    /* size of the type-ahead buffer */
#define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
#define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
#define PIPE_BUF        4096    /* # bytes in atomic write to a pipe */
#define XATTR_NAME_MAX   255    /* # chars in an extended attribute name */
#define XATTR_SIZE_MAX 65536    /* size of an extended attribute value (64k) */
#define XATTR_LIST_MAX 65536    /* size of extended attribute namelist (64k) */

#define RTSIG_MAX     32

#endif
```

And this file is defining `PATH_MAX` in Linux.

`limits.h` is a C standard header defining language (not system) related macros.